# Why don't working ListView in base template? How called view from base template for ech url? Django 2.1.5

Tags: python, django

I want display list of all comments in db on sidebar (template "base_generic.html"). I do this with ListView, but this didn't working.

**views.py**

```
class CommentListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "base_generic.html"
    model = Comment
    paginate_by = 5
```

**base_generic.html**

```
{% block sidebar %}
<h1>Comments list</h1>
{% if comment_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for comment in comment_list %}
        <p>{{ comment.author }} ({{ comment.comment_date }}) {{ comment.description|safe }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>There are no comments.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-comment_date"]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.description)
```

DB has a comments, but on the page shown "There are no comments".
How called it from base template for ech url?

Comment: How are you calling that view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman oi... I don't called this view in url... How called it from base template for ech url?

Comment: You can't do that, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it this way. A URL maps to a single view, you can't have multiple views for one URL.

If you need to populate a sidebar in the base template for every page, you need to use a custom template tag: an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `comments_list` instead of `comment_list`

Here is how it works

```
'%s_list' % object_list.model._meta.model_name
```

Also you can set `context_object_name` and use that name in your template

```
class CommentListView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'custom name. comments for example'
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Generics view you should use `object_list` name for get data in templates or you can change it by `context_object_name` .

```
class Foo(generics.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'comments'
```

---

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DanielRoseman for help.

In folder with app create folder "**templatetags**" with empty file "**__init.py__**" and next file:

**all_comments.py**

```
from django import template
from post.models import Comment

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('post/comment_list.html')    #register function in template
def comment_list():
    comments = Comment.objects.filter()[0:5]         #take 5 last comments
    return {'comments': comments}
```

Then create template "**comment_list.html**":

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p>{{ comment.author }} ({{ comment.comment_date }}) {{ comment.description|safe }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Then load our tag in "**base_generic.html**"

```
...
{% load all_comments %}
...
<div class="sidebar">
    {% comment_list %}
</div>
```

[More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)